# How to perform Facebook Login in android

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I am working on an app in which i need to have facebook login feature. But i am getting no clear picture for how to go about it.

- First of all I am getting the code so there i dont think i will have problem
- Secondly in order to just include facebook login do my device need to have facebook application or apk installed on the device.. (this is my biggest concern). Since i am working on a device which has less internal memory and also latest facebook apk is of 40 mb size.
- Thirdly how to Generate the keyhash in facebook developers page.
- Forthly how to include the facebook sdk in android studio

[image]

in the above image it's asking for the keyhases... how to get it... i m not getting any clue

Comment: follow this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

Comment: I went through this link... it's telling to install facebook.apk which i dont want due to memory issue... My second point says that is it compulsory to install facebook.apk file

Comment: sir follow step 3 and hope so it will work

Comment: @anand Have you solved this ???

Comment: @HeshanSandeepa ..  I have been able to integerate the FB login... now FB developers provide the gradle for facebook sdk... so you can include that and thus ready to go...